# Replace item in a list by checking part of it

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[item1(130.35),item2(140.10),item2(140.25),item2(130.05)]
```

I want to replace each item with something different from another list by checking the first digits of its number.
For example all 130s replaceditem1,all 140s replaceditem2:

```
[replaceditem1,replaceditem2,replaceditem2,replaceditem1]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want but perhaps `[replaceditem1 if i == 130 else replaceditem2 if i == 140 else i for i in lst]` ?

Comment: create new, empty list and use for-loop to get every element from old list and check if it has `130` or `140` and then add to new list `replaceditem1` or `replaceditem2`

Comment: What's the actual list look like?  is `item1(130.35)` a call to `item1()` or is it a string like `"item1(130.35)"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to:

- define a regular expression to extract the desired number - `item\d+\((\d+)\.\d+\)` would work for this set of inputs
- define a dictionary of replacements (would help to keep the replacement logic clean and if you need to scale the solution)
- iterate over all items in the list, extract the numbers and see if there is a replacements for a number - if not, we'll just add the item unchanged

Demo:

```
>>> l = ["item1(130.35)", "item2(140.10)", "item2(140.25)", "item2(130.05)"]

>>> import re

>>> pattern = re.compile(r"item\d+\((\d+)\.\d+\)")

>>> replacements = {
...     '130': 'replaceditem1',
...     '140': 'replaceditem2'
... }

>>> result = []

>>> for item in l:
...     match = pattern.match(item)
...     if match:
...         result.append(replacements.get(match.group(1), item))
...     else:
...         result.append(item)

>>> result
['replaceditem1', 'replaceditem2', 'replaceditem2', 'replaceditem1']
```

---

Let's go over the regular expression:

- `\d+` matches one or more consecutive digits
- `\(` and `\)` would match literal open and closing parenthesis - needed to be escaped since they have a special meaning
- `\.` would match a literal dot
- `(\d+)` is a *capturing group* that would capture one or more consecutive digits

Comment: What about in the case where `item1(130.35)` is a function call and not a string?

Comment: Well apparently the OP just selected your answer, so my comment above is irrelevant. +1

Comment: @leaf yeah, I assumed the OP had these items as strings, looks like the assumption was correct. Thanks.